# How to change ComboBox placeholder foreground in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, combobox, uwp-xaml

I would like to change ComboBox placeholder color in my demo UWP app. So I tried to create static resources:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">

                    <ContentControl x:Name="PlaceholderTextContentPresenter"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding PlaceholderText}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Using:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Transparent"
              PlaceholderText="Выбор оператора" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
        <x:String>iPhone 11</x:String>
        <x:String>iPhone 12</x:String>
        <x:String>Xiaomi Red Mi</x:String>
        <x:String>Samsung Galaxy 10</x:String>

        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
```

Foreground in placeholder changed correctly but ComboBox is disappeared. How can I will change ComboBox placeholder foreground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to change ComboBox placeholder foreground in UWP

UWP ComboBox contains [`PlaceholderForeground`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox.placeholderforeground?view=winrt-19041) propety, if you want to chage the default one, you just need to give it specific value like the following. And please not the property avaiable in version 16299 or higher.

```
<ComboBox
    Grid.Row="1"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    Background="Transparent"
    Foreground="White"
    PlaceholderText="Выбор оператора"
    PlaceholderForeground="DarkBlue">

    <x:String>iPhone 11</x:String>
    <x:String>iPhone 12</x:String>
    <x:String>Xiaomi Red Mi</x:String>
    <x:String>Samsung Galaxy 10</x:String>

</ComboBox>
```